# ImportError: No module named pandas when using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a project with the following structure:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── rules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── budget.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── budget_test.py
```

Obviously, the `budget_test.py` is testing the `budget.py` module.

```
from .. import budget

class TestBudget:
...
```

and the `budget.py` starts with:

```
import pandas as pd
```

When I launch the module manually, the import runs fine.
When I launch pytest, I get an ImportError about pandas:

> ImportError: No module named pandas

En though the virtualenv is activated and pandas is part of the installed packages:

```
pip freeze
```

> ...
>   pandas==1.0.1
>   ...

Is there any reason pytest cannot find the packages installed in the virtual environment?

Surprisingly, running `pytest` fails when `python -m pytest` is succesful

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks. if you put your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common practice to use `python -m pytest` to be able to find all modules in the current environment. To be a bit more specific - this is needed to find modules *inside packages*.

You can read more about the -m switch rationale and behavior in the related [PEP-338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/).